# Where should i sign?

Tags: loans

I'm in the process of buying a vehicle. My uncle is helping me out by cosigning for me. On the contract there is a buyer and a co-buyer line that requires signatures. Where do i sign.

Comment: If you care for your uncle you could do him a favor and not sign and encourage him to do the same.

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking this question.  If you are obtaining a loan, the *lender* will tell you where to sign and what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Who will own the vehicle? It sounds like that's you, which makes you the buyer.